# Menu list with borders not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a menu with 5 items. The idea is that there is a border between each.

The issue is that some of the menu items need to be double lined, but when this happens, the borders are all over the place.

I've been looking at the code for an hour almost and not sure how to correct this.

I could just have them single lined, but that goes against the design.

**JSFIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/69CSf/

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-color:black;
}
#menu {
    width:500px;
    top:100px;
    -border:solid 1px #ffff00;
    height:40px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:#FFF;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    width:19%;
    height:40px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:9px;
    vertical-align:center;
}
li~li {
    border-left: 3px solid #FFFFFF
}
li>a:hover {
    color:#FFF;
}
li>a {
    color:rgb(200, 200, 200);
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Philosophy</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Your Trainer</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Word of Mouth</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/69CSf/2/ you need something like this? You can use display:table-cell on li elements?

Comment: what you want actually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `display` value from `inline-block` to `table-cell` and change `vertical-align` value to `middle` (`vertical-align:center` does not exist at all).

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/69CSf/5/)

Comment: Thats perfect! Something so simple! Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to center the double lined text with the other text? at the moment the top line is lined up, but would be prefered if the middle of the 2 lines is lined up.

Comment: @Joey : Yes, it is possible and I've updated my post with solution and example.

Comment: @Joey :everything that is specified in my post and also I've remover `padding-top:9px`.

Answer (score 0):

you have this `vertical-align:center;`, change it to `vertical-align:middle;` for `LI` element